# Is there a good reason for the use of the word "exactly" here?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I was reading through my linear algebra book and the Replacement Theorem states:

> Let $V$ be a vector space that is generated by a set $G$ containing exactly $n$ vectors and let $L$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$ containing exactly $m$ vectors. Then $m \leq n$ and there exists a set $H$ containing exactly $n-m$ vectors such that $L \cup H$ generates $V$.

I noticed the use of the word "exactly" here. Is this even necessary? Is there a case where $G$ has $n$ vectors but not *exactly* $n$ vectors???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say $G$ has $n$ vectors but do not specify that it has exactly $n$ vectors, it might have more.  The writer wants to be clear that there are not more than $n$.  The claim would fail if $G$ could have more than $n$ or $H$ could have more than $m$.